# Sort Two dimensional table by value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How do I sort a created list on it's value ? 
this is my result :

```
array (size=10)
  1 => int 0
  2 => int 2
  3 => int 3
  4 => int 2
  5 => int 2
  6 => int 1
  7 => int 0
  8 => int 2
  9 => int 1
  10 => int 2
```

While this is what I want to have :

```
array (size=10)
  3 => int 3
  2 => int 2
  4 => int 2
  5 => int 2
  8 => int 2
  10 => int 2 
  6 => int 1  
  9 => int 1
  1 => int 0
  7 => int 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the php array sort functions, you'll probably need something like this...

```
$array = arsort($array);
```

Comment: *you'll probably need* Have you even tested your code?

Comment: I need to test something as simple as this? It must take you about 5 years to write one script. lol